# Rabbitmq - consuming and publishing on same channel?

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika

I have two python processes connected to Rabbitmq via pika. Each consumes a set of topics which the other publishes as a response. One uses the SelectConnection and the other uses the TornadoConnection.

Both are currently just test programs which simulate a conversation between a user and my server, and each program's on_message() is simply hard-coded to branch on the routing_key received and publish the appropriate response to it's counterpart.

Originally, after a random amount of time, typically no longer than 2 minutes, I'd get an error like:

```
UnexpectedFrame: Basic.publish: (505) UNEXPECTED_FRAME - expected content header for class 60, got non content header frame instead
```

After searching through numerous posts here on stack overflow and elsewhere, I've come to understand that this error has to do with a race condition where something is being consumed before the basic_publish was complete.

I've made a change to my code so that rather than doing an immediate basic_publish(), I pass a callback to connection.add_timeout() with a delay of 1 second.  After making this change, I've been able to have numerous runs where two processes have a "conversation" with each other for > 1hr without reproducing the error.

My question is, is this just a hack which works only because I'm simulating one user? Do I need to have 2 separate channels for consuming and publishing?

```
def on_message(self, unused_channel, basic_deliver, properties, body):
    if self._sibling_app_id == properties.app_id:
        self.dispatch_message(basic_deliver, properties, body)


def dispatch_message(self, basic_deliver, properties, body):
    (user_id, msg_type) = basic_deliver.routing_key.rsplit('.', 1)

    if "login-response" == msg_type:
        print body
    elif "gid-assignment" == msg_type:
        print body
    elif "tutor-logout" == msg_type:
        print body
    elif "tutor-turn" == msg_type:
        message = "i don't know"
        routing_key = "%s.input" % user_id
        callback = self.delayed_publish_message(routing_key, message)
        self.schedule_next_message(callback, 1)
    elif "nlu" == msg_type:
        message = "dnk"
        routing_key = "%s.nlu-response" % user_id
        callback = self.delayed_publish_message(routing_key, message)
        self.schedule_next_message(callback, 1)
    else:
        print "invalid message-type: %s" % msg_type
        print body

def delayed_publish_message(self, routing_key, message):
    """returns a callback which can be passed to schedule_next_message()"""
    def delayed_publish_cb():
        self.publish_message(routing_key, message)
    return delayed_publish_cb


def schedule_next_message(self, cb, publish_interval=None):
    if self._stopping:
        return
    if publish_interval is None:
        publish_interval = self.PUBLISH_INTERVAL
    if -1 == publish_interval:
        return
    self._connection.add_timeout(publish_interval, cb)


def publish_message(self, routing_key, message):
    if self._stopping:
        return
    properties = pika.BasicProperties(app_id=self._app_id,
                                                          content_type='text/plain')
    self._channel.basic_publish(self.EXCHANGE, routing_key,
                                                 message, properties)
```

Comment: Which process was throwing that exception, the one with `SelectConnection` or the one with the `TornadoConnection`?

Comment: always the SelectConnection

Comment: Interesting. According to [this bug report](https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/112), this same bug with `SelectConnection` was fixed with this [pull request](https://github.com/pika/pika/pull/173) back in 2012. I'm not sure if it's a regression (doesn't look like it based on a quick glance at the current source), a similar issue with a different cause, or if the original fix missed some cases.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that the mention of that particular fix in my searching.  Does this mean that my code is supposed to work, even without the 1 sec delays added?

Comment: @dano thanks for your comments, while I noticed the pull request before, I failed to notice the data.  I probably wouldn't have figured this out if you hadn't mentioned that

Answer (score 9):

A channel is to be used uni-directional. The [AMQP protocol specification](http://www.amqp.org/sites/amqp.org/files/amqp.pdf) is very clear about that:

> An AMQP Session correlates two unidirectional Channels to form a bidirectional, sequential conversation between two Containers. A
>   single Connection may have multiple independent Sessions active
>   simultaneously, up to the negotiated Channel limit. Both Connections
>   and Sessions are modeled by each peer as endpoints that store local
>   and last known remote state regarding the Connection or Session in
>   question.

Thus you are supposed to use an input and an output channel for your application.

Comment: You're quoting from the AMQP 1.0 specification, but RabbitMQ implements version 0.9.1. Is there a similar clause in the 0.9.1 spec?

Comment: The 0.9.1 spec falls short of explaining an AMQP session. But there is a hint in section 4.7 (Content Ordering Guarantees). On the other hand: Channels are really kind of a dumb wire. Speaking on both sides at the same time is not a good idea and leads to frame errors.

Answer (score 1):

I did my commits, was about to go to bed and suddenly I figured it out.  I turns out that the python tutorials on rabbitmq.com still say to install pika with:

```
 sudo pip install pika==0.9.8
```

And while 0.9.8 came out sometime in 2012, I think the fix was added sometime *after* that release. with 0.9.9 being released sometime in 2013

So, I did:

```
sudo pip uninstall pika
```

followed by the installation instructions on the pika site:

```
sudo pip install pika
```

then I replaced all of my connection.add_timeout(1, delayed_publish_cb) with basic_publish(), crossed my fingers, ran it and my two processes exchanged about 200,000 messages with each other in less than 5 minutes without any problems

Good to know that the bug fix from back in 2012 still works.

I'll have to let the rabbitmq folks know to update their tutorial.